# How selecting javascript code to dropdown option from webbrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I write a code for doing hot phone verify. But when I hit click then all field are filled but there is showing a “message”. How do I work on this code?

```
       <div id="iPhoneSection" style="display: none">
                <div class="InputRow">
                    <label id="iSmsHeading" for="DisplayPhoneCountryISO" class="Label" style="display: none"></label>
                    <div class="bottompad">
                        <select id="DisplayPhoneCountryISO" name="DisplayPhoneCountryISO" aria-labelledby="iSmsHeading"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div id="PhoneError" class="ErrMsg prooferror" style="display: none" aria-live="assertive" aria-relevant="text" aria-atomic="true"></div>
                    <div id="PhoneContainer" class="phcontainer"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="toppad">
                    Verify phone via:
                    <input id="idSMSChannel" type="radio" name="nameMNCChannel" value="SMS" class="inlineRadio" checked />
                    <label for="idSMSChannel">Text</label>
                    <input id="idVoiceChannel" type="radio" name="nameMNCChannel" value="Voice" class="inlineRadio" />
                    <label for="idVoiceChannel">Call</label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Please check code below:

```
     webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("DisplayPhoneCountryISO").SetAttribute("value", "BD");

        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("DisplayPhoneNumber").SetAttribute("value", mobile.Text);



        HtmlElementCollection elc = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)
        {
            if (el.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit"))
            {
                el.InvokeMember("Click");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please check & give me 1 good road for this issue.